# Powershell Array not working in WinPE but OK on Windows 7

Tags: arrays, powershell, winpe

Hi Firstly I have WinPE 4 and Powershell version 4 running other powershell scripts fine in my environment.

The issue is with displaying Array information.. On windows 7 running PS Version 4 this works great...

I have a Function rounding the size off which we dont need in this example.

```
$a = @()
$diskdrive = gwmi win32_diskdrive
foreach($drive in $diskdrive){

$InterFaceType = "$($Drive.InterfaceType)"
If(!($InterFaceType -eq "USB")){
$Size = "$($drive.size)"
$DriveModel = "`nDrive: $($drive.deviceid.substring(4))  Model: $($drive.model)" 
$Size = Get-OptimalSize $Size
$Result = $DriveModel + "     " + $Size
$a += $Result
}
}

$a = $a | Sort-Object

$Drive1 = $a[0] 
$Drive2 = $a[1]
$Drive3 = $a[2]
$Drive4 = $a[3]
$Drive5 = $a[4]
$Drive6 = $a[5]

$Drive1 = $Drive1.trim()
$Drive2 = $Drive2.trim()
$Drive3 = $Drive3.trim()
$Drive4 = $Drive4.trim()
$Drive5 = $Drive5.trim()
$Drive6 = $Drive6.trim()
```

In Windows 7 $Drive1,2,3,4,5,6 will display the following info about the Drive detected.

Drive: PHYSICALDRIVE0  Model: ST3500418AS     465.76 GB

In WinPE $Drive1,2,3,4,5,6 Are Blank...

However $Result ( which i add to my array ) is not. As soon as i take that $Result and add to the $a array in WinPE its like it clears it?

I need to loop through the for each and add each pass to an array and this is how you do it, but as WinPE is acting differently I am looking at creating a brand new dynamic variable with each pass.

For eg.

Take first pass call $Result1, then $Result2 and $result3 etc.

Maybe if I use an actual Variable ( like the $Result which appears to display in WinPE) i can work round the odd behaviour of WinPE??

Any help appreciated.

Just to add the behaviour is reminiscent of the string not being trimmed as when compiling the code on Windows 7 it was doing the same until i added the trim to the $drive variables. However i have already trimmed the variables and in WinPE it still will not show when called. Do i have to trim further? just an idea

for eg.... i was doing this.

```
    If($a[0]){
$Radio1.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 500
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 15    
$Radio1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$Radio1.TabIndex = 5
$Radio1.Text = $Drive1
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 27
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 260
$Radio1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$Radio1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$Radio1.Name = "Radio1"
$form1.Controls.Add($Radio1)

}
```

Using $a and not an array this is what happens.

If i do this

```
$msg = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]
$msg::Show($a[0])
```

I get nothing in winpe.
If i do this...

```
$msg = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]
$msg::Show($a)
```

it outputs the information, however i cannot use just $a as that is only the last pass in the loop..

All this is fine in windows 7..

How can i create a New variable on each pass without an Array?

So $Result1, $Result2 etc then i can call the actual variable for the info not the array index? that might work?

Comment: Try changing `$a += $Results` to `[Array]$a = $a + $Results` and see if that behaves better. It sounds like it isn't setting up $a as an array so it isn't iterating new records, it's just resetting it.

Comment: Hi that has worked great thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Adding my suggestion as an Answer so the question can be resolved.
Try changing `$a += $Results` to `[Array]$a = $a + $Results` and see if that behaves better. It sounds like it isn't setting up $a as an array so it isn't iterating new records, it's just resetting it.

Comment: i have another strange issue with winpe - code works in win7 not winpe and think yo umight have an idea why?